# How to append trigger property with createElement

Tags: vue.js

```
<el-popover
   ref="popover1">
     <div>
       content
     </div>
</el-popover>
<el-button v-popover:popover1>Button</el-button>
```

I am not sure how to call `v-popover:popover1` property but I want to ask how can I create such a property via `createElement` method dynamically?

```
return createElement('span', {}, [
    createElement('el-popover', {
      props: {
        ref: component.props.ref,
      }
    }, 'content'),
    createElement('el-button', {
      props: {
        'v-popover': component.props.ref
      }
    }, 'trigger')
  ])
```

Above way didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate `v-popover:popover1` in your template, you can do it via the [`directives` property in `createElement`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth), i.e.:

```
createElement('el-button', {
    directives: [
        {
            name: 'popover',
            arg: component.props.ref
        }
    ]
}, 'trigger')
```

The [nomenclature of a VueJS binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments):

```
v-popover:popover1
  ├─────┘ ├──────┘
  └name   └argument
```

Comment: There is one correction actually, I've found the solution with using the directive name as `popover` instead of `v-popover`

Comment: @berkan My bad: the directive name should be without the `v-` prefix. I've updated my answer now. Glad to hear that you've got it to work.